# How to post checked and unchecked values

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i have three checkboxes.I want to post these three.Checked is one and unchecked is 0.Table contain three columns.I want to insert 1 for checked and 0 fr unchecked.

```
 <label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='check_1' class='example1' value='1' checked/>India</label>
 <label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='check_2' class='example1' value='1' class='termcls'checked />China</label>
 <label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='check_3' class='example1' value='1' checked/>America</label>
```

How to do this..

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: @GolezTrol , hmm  , maybe can!, you can put hidden input with same name of chekcbox with 0 value!

Comment: And then hope that the right one is posted... Why take the risk, if it's so simple to check in PHP?

Comment: you must keep two sides , your right , it's simple to check in PHP!

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes don't work like that. If checked they post their values, if not checked they post nothing. So on the server, just check if you got a value for the name of the checkbox and base your logic on that. That's *way* easier and safer than trying to implement a client-side alternative for this standard behaviour.

It's as simple as 1,2,3:

```
$check1Checked = isset($_POST['check_1']);
$check2Checked = isset($_POST['check_2']);
$check3Checked = isset($_POST['check_3']);
```

Or, if you want 0 and 1, just cast this boolean outcome to int.

```
$check1Checked = (int)isset($_POST['check_1']);
$check2Checked = (int)isset($_POST['check_2']);
$check3Checked = (int)isset($_POST['check_3']);
```

Note that in either case the actual value of the posted checkbox is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
$check1Checked = (isset($_POST['check_1']))?1:0;
$check2Checked = (isset($_POST['check_2']))?1:0;
$check3Checked = (isset($_POST['check_3']))?1:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

submit your form and check it in logical part in this way

```
if(@$_POST['check_1']=='1')
{
   echo "1st is checked";
}
else
{
   echo "1st not checked";
}
```